# How to show that a quaternionic matrix is not a product of two involutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

**Problem.** Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ be a matrix over the real quaternion ring $\mathbb{H}.$ Prove that it is similar to its inverse, but is not a product of two involutions. Can it be a product of commutators of involutions?

A square matrix $A$ over a ring is called similar to $B$ if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PBP^{-1}.$ A square matrix $T$ over a ring is called an involution if $T^2=I$
is the identity matrix. A square matrix $A$ over a ring is called a commutator of involution if there exist involutions $T, S$ such that $A=TST^{-1}S^{-1}.$

I have shown $$A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-i&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},$$ and $$A=\begin{pmatrix}ij&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}ij&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$

But I don't answer this remaining. I don't know why it is not a product of two involutions. If this is true, then it can be a product of commutators of involutions, can't it? Thanks for all your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we had $A = UV\ldots UV$, with $U$, $V$ involutions, then $V(A^{-1})V^{-1} = A$. Therefore, there would exists an involution $V$ that conjugates $A^{-1}$ to $A$.  Now, we know that
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}ij&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}ij&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$

Moreover, it is easy to see that the centralizer of $A$ equals
$$\begin{pmatrix}a+ b i&0\\0&\star\end{pmatrix}$$, with $a$, $b$ not both $0$. So now the question is: can a matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}a+ b i&0\\0&\star\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}ij&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ be an involution? Equivalently, can we have
$$((a+bi) ij)^2 = 1$$
Let's calculate:
$$(-b + a i) j (- b + a i) j= \cdots = - a^2 - b^2 < 0$$
so it cannot equal $1$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Do you have any information on the remaining question? Can it be a product of commutators of involutions?

Comment: @Trần Nam Sơn: Sorry, I don't right now.  Where is the problem from? Perhaps I can find out more info on it.

Comment: Excuse me. Please tell me more about it. I still don't understand why it can't be a product of two involutions.

Comment: @TrầnNamSơn:  Above we showed which elements can conjugate $A^{-1}$ to $A$ ( a product of the given one and a stabilizer of $A$) Among them, there are no involutions.

Comment: Yes. I understand. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Trần Nam Sơn: You are welcome!  The other part of the problem is not clear to me.  We cannot use determinants ( so it seems).  A product of involutions should have det $1$ for a commutative field... Maybe it is possible in this case